# Xamarin android Sqlite.net C# how to convert synchronous query to async task

Tags: android, sqlite, asynchronous, xamarin, async-await

I've got a method for my xamarin android app that checks a sqlite db for login credentials.  I'm fairly new to async tasks and was wondering how to change the method below to an async method.

I know I can change the call to the method easily enough with await and changing the calling method to an async relay command but how do I change the query method?

```
    public static bool CheckLogin(string userName, string password)
    {
        bool valid = false;
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "..", dbName);
        using (var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
        {
            try {
               var user = conn.Query<User>("select * from tblUsers where nLogin = ? and nPassword = ?", userName, password);
                if (user.Count>0)
                {
                    valid = true;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static Task<bool> CheckLogin(string userName, string password)
{
    return await Task.Run(delegate{
        bool valid = false;
    string dbPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "..", dbName);
    using (var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
    {
        try {
           var user = conn.Query<User>("select * from tblUsers where nLogin = ? and nPassword = ?", userName, password);
            if (user.Count>0)
            {
                valid = true;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    return valid;
    });
}
```

This is not tested so maybe there is a syntax error or something.

```
bool loginValid = await CheckLogin(user,pass);
```

But generally this should do ;)

This code will not block the calling thread and should be exactly what you want.

I know you posted you want to use SQLiteAsyncConnection, but I think its better to have the async part code on your own side.

Comment: Only thing missing from this was returning the await Task.Run.  Otherwise it works Thanks.  Just curious though why do you think it's better to have async on my own code?

Comment: Often other code locks something or executes something on the main thread. I found it to be easier to find these sort of bugs when I know that external code always is synchronous which make it easy to test. Maybe thats bad design, but thats how I do it and it helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task<bool> CheckLogin (string userName, string password)
    {
        bool valid = false;
    string dbPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "..", dbName);
    using (var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
    {enter code here
        try {
           var user = conn.Query<User>("select * from tblUsers where nLogin = ? and nPassword = ?", userName, password);
            if (user.Count>0)
            {
                valid = true;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    return valid;
    }
```

And you can call your method like :

```
await CheckLogin ("username", "password");
```

Comment: That isn't really going to run asyncrhonously though.  I'm looking for something that will run using the   SQLiteAsyncConnection.